# Увеличение элемента в границах его самого

Tags: html, css

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы при наведении на элемент img он увеличивался в своих границах и не залазил на соседние элементы?

С левой стороной элемента я разобрался, а вот с правой нет, при увеличении залазит на белый элемент справа.

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->

    <link
      rel="icon"
      type="image/png"
      sizes="32x32"
      href="./images/favicon-32x32.png"
    />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik:wght@400;500;700&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

    <script
      type="module"
      src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@7.1.0/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"
    ></script>
    <script
      nomodule
      src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@7.1.0/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"
    ></script>
    <title>Frontend Mentor | Product preview card component</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="product-container">
          <div class="content">
            <img
              class="image"
              src="images/image-product-desktop.jpg"
              alt="Perfume Image"
            />

            <div class="text-block">
              <div class="main-text">
                <div class="name">
                  <p>Perfume</p>
                  <h1>Gabrielle Essence Eau De Parfum</h1>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="description">
                <p>
                  A floral, solar and voluptuous interpretation composed by
                  Olivier Polge, Perfumer-Creator for the House of CHANEL.
                </p>
              </div>
              <div class="prices">
                <h2 class="main-price">$149.99</h2>
                <p class="second-price">$169.99</p>
              </div>
              <button class="btn">
                <ion-icon class="icon" name="cart-outline"></ion-icon> Add to
                Cart
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="attribution">
        Challenge by
        <a href="https://www.frontendmentor.io?ref=challenge" target="_blank"
          >Frontend Mentor</a
        >. Coded by <a href="#">Your Name Here</a>.
      </div>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik:wght@400;500;700&display=swap");

:root {
  --dark-cyan: hsl(158, 36%, 37%);
  --cream: hsl(30, 38%, 92%);

  /* Neutral */
  --very-dark-blue: hsl(212, 21%, 14%);
  --dark-grayish-blue: hsl(228, 12%, 48%);
  --white: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Montserrat", "Fraunces", serif;
  background-color: var(--cream);
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.product-container {
  background-color: var(--white);
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 650px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 20px rgba(215, 210, 210, 0.2);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.content img {
  width: 50%;
  transition: all 0.7s;
  border-radius: 25px 0px 0px 25px;
}

.content img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.image {
  height: 500px;
  width: 325px;
}

.text-block {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 2rem 2rem 2rem 2rem;
  width: 50%;
}

.name p {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  color: var(--dark-grayish-blue);
}

.name h1 {
  font-family: "Fraunces";
  line-height: 1em;
  font-weight: 700;
  max-width: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.description p {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.8em;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: var(--dark-grayish-blue);
  max-width: 250px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.prices {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: stretch;
  column-gap: 20px;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 29px;
}

.prices .main-price {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: var(--dark-cyan);
  font-family: "Fraunces", serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.prices .second-price {
  font-size: 15px;
  text-decoration: line-through;
  color: var(--dark-grayish-blue);
}

.btn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  column-gap: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: none;
  background-color: var(--dark-cyan);
  color: var(--white);
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.icon {
  font-weight: 500;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  color: var(--white);
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: var(--white);
  color: var(--dark-cyan);
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 0 var(--dark-cyan) inset,
    -2px -2px 0 var(--dark-cyan) inset;
}

.btn:hover .icon {
  color: var(--dark-cyan);
}
```

Comment: поместите ваш `img` в `div` и задайте этому `div`-у нужные размеры и параметр `overflow: hidden`, таким образом картинка будет менять размеры в пределах этого `div`-а